# Why Allah (S.T.) did not told "Ya Muhammad (pbuh)" in the Holy Quran?

Tags: quran, prophet-muhammad, quran-translation

Why Allah Subhanahu Wa Ta'ala did not call our prophet (Sallallahu Alaihi wa Sallam) like "Ya Muhammad!..." in the Holy book Quranul Karim?

Is it okay to address with this if anything Allah Subhanahu wa Ta'ala told addressing our prophet? Example:

وَأْمُرْ أَهْلَكَ بِالصَّلَاةِ وَاصْطَبِرْ عَلَيْهَا لَا نَسْأَلُكَ رِزْقًا نَّحْنُ نَرْزُقُكَ وَالْعَاقِبَةُ لِلتَّقْوَى

Is it okay to translate like:

"And (**Hey Muhammad Sallallhu Alaihi wa Sallam!**) enjoin prayer upon your family [and people] and be steadfast therein. We ask you not for provision; We provide for you, and the [best] outcome is for [those of] righteousness."(20:132)

The Imam of our local mosque said, "Allah subhanahu wa ta'la never called Rasulullah Sallallahu Alaihi wa Sallam with his name, because, calling by one's name is not that respectful. So, Allah subhanahu wa ta'ala avoided it. But used in case of other prophet so that people could understand the respect of our prophet (pbuh). So, translating like this is not permissible."

Answer (score 2):

All praise to Allah Subhan o Taala and blessings on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His Family and Companions.

Allah Swt has addressed Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him with most beautiful names, some of them are

**Ahmad, Amin, Bashir, Burhan, Khatem, Dai, Rauf, Rahim, Siraj, Munir, Ta-Ha, Ya-Sin, Abd, Muhammad, Muddaththir, Muzammil, Mustafa, Mujtaba, Nadhir, Hâdî. peace be upon Him**.

And when some title is given to someone it means that someone has a very higher rank among others that he is called by his title and not just like **O'**.(Name).

We could see in Quran Allah Swt when mentioning name of Muhammad peace be upon him 4 times as "Muhammad peace be upon him" is in a quoting way like

"**And Mohammed (peace and blessings be upon him) is purely* a Noble Messenger; 3:144**

**"..Muhammad is the father of no man among you."33:40**

**"..As for the faithful who do good works and believe in what has beeen revealed to Muhammad – which is the Truth form their Lord – He will forgive them their sins and ennoble their state."47:2**

**"Muhammad is God’s apostle."48:29**

Allah Swt is quoting his name here but when he is calling to Muhammad peace be upon him he is saying with beautiful names as Ya-sin, Ta-Ha ,Muzammil ,Muddathir...

And the word **"Hey"** is not appropriate at all because it also means as exclaiming with annoyance.

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.

Comment: Just wanted to make a notice that there are arguments about whether Ta-ha and Ya-sin are really names of the Prophet (PBUH) or not.. Some say it is,, others say it is just like 'الم,حم,' and other letters that arevat the beginning of some Surahs.

Comment: Jajakallah for your answer, but two things, one is @AbdelRahmanShamel mentioned.and another thing you did not conclude that his words are correct or not rather you emphasized on 'Hey'. It is not the main matter of our talk as it is not a matter of choosing word rather a matter of translating. Because, you can translate 'Ya' as 'Hello', 'Hey', 'O' ' etc.So, it is my earnest request to clear the matters. Jajakallah.

Comment: Majority of scholars have mentioned Yaseen as a name of Muhammad peace be upon him in their tafasir of Quran.